# Clarification on Mesivta's calculations of Shtut

Tags: money, bava-metzia

The Mesivta on B"M 50 brings the following table summarizing  different ways of calculations of Shtut:

[image]

I couldn't understand, if 1 out of 6 makes 16.6%, how come 9 out of 60 make 8.3%.

Please help me to understand the logic.

Comment: Where do you get 9/60 from?

Comment: 8.33% of 60 is 5. Chances are that whoever prepared the table just goofed and put in the wrong numerator (or misread a 9 in their notes as a 5).

Comment: @DonielF The first line - Shtut is one out of 6 i.e. 16%. 9 out of 60 makes 15% not 8.3%.

Comment: @AlBerko But what is 9/60? What does that fraction represent?

Comment: @DonielF If the value is 60 and 51 is paid (last row) so the Ona'a is 9 out of the value of 60.